# JSON object in array retrofit

Tags: android, arrays, json, retrofit

i have json response like this

```
    [{
    "id": 94973,
    "slug": "la-liga-real-betis-1-1-barcelona-29-januari-2017",
    "title": {
        "rendered": "La Liga: Real Betis 1-1 Barcelona 29 Januari 2017"
    }
}, {
    "id": 94957,
    "slug": "fa-chelsea-4-0-brentford-28-januari-2017",
    "title": {
        "rendered": "FA: Chelsea 4-0 Brentford, 28 Januari 2017"
    }
}, {
    "id": 94944,
    "slug": "serie-a-ac-milan-1-2-napoli-22-januari-2017",
    "title": {
        "rendered": "Serie A: AC Milan 1-2 Napoli, 22 Januari 2017"
    }
}]
```

what im trying to do is get a value of rendered title insetead of id and slug

this is my retrofit class

```
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Coba>> call, Response<List<Coba>> response) {
            try {
                List<Coba> jsonResponse = response.body();
                data= new ArrayList<>();
                data.addAll(jsonResponse);
                adapter = new MyAdapter(data);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                Log.i("HASIL", "onResponse: "+data);
            }catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("onResponse", "There is an error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

how to get that value using retfrofit?

Comment: from what i see i guess your Coba class has getters and setters. So you call getter and retrieve the values. something like `list.get(position).gettitle().getRendered()`

Comment: nice..im already make the class pojo..and do your suggest..and its work..

Comment: glad it worked. that's the added advantage of retrofit convertors

Answer (score 0):

create a class

```
public class CobaResponse { 
    Arraylist<Coba> cobas;
    getCobas(){ return cobas; }

    class Coba {
        int id;
        String slug;
        Map<String,String> title;

        getId(){ return id; }
        getSlug(){ return slug; }
        getMap(){ return title; }
    }
}
```

Use that model in retrofit interfaces.

```
@Get("/requesturl")
Call<CobaResponse> getCobas();
```

Finally onResponse method.

```
Response.body().getCobas.get(0).getId();
```